# Convert string of list of JSON which is separated by '\n' to list of JSON(data from mixpanel) in python

Tags: python, json, mixpanel

The data I retrieved from Mixpanel has the format:

```
"{"event":"info1xxxxx","Id":"0001"}
 {"event":"info2xxxxx","Id":"0002"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003","other_key":"value"}..."
```

It's a string of list of JSON which are separated by '\n'. And each JSON may have a different structure.

I expect to convert it to list of JSON like:

```
[{"event":"info1xxxxx","Id":"0001"},
 {"event":"info2xxxxx","Id":"0002"},
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003"},
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003","other_key":"value"},...]
```

How could I do this? Looking for the help, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am not certain exactly about the format of the string since I am not familiar with Mixpanel, but assuming you do not have `'\n'` at the end of the string

```
s = "{"event":"info1xxxxx","Id":"0001"}
 {"event":"info2xxxxx","Id":"0002"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003","other_key":"value"}"""
json_list = [json.loads(e) for e in s.split('\n')]
```

In case you have `'\n'` at the end of the string

```
s = "{"event":"info1xxxxx","Id":"0001"}
 {"event":"info2xxxxx","Id":"0002"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003"}
 {"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003","other_key":"value"}
"""

json_list = [json.loads(e) for e in s[:-1].split('\n')]
```

For both cases the value of `json_list` will be:

```
[
    {'event': 'info1xxxxx', 'Id': '0001'},
    {'event': 'info2xxxxx', 'Id': '0002'},
    {'event': 'info3xxxxx', 'Id': '0003'},
    {'event': 'info3xxxxx', 'Id': '0003', 'other_key': 'value'}
]
```

Comment: There is no `\n` at the end of the string for my data. And I tried with the first method then got an error: "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)". But this question has been solved by Andrej. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `str.splitlines`:

```py
import json

s = """\
{"event":"info1xxxxx","Id":"0001"}
{"event":"info2xxxxx","Id":"0002"}
{"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003"}
{"event":"info3xxxxx","Id":"0003","other_key":"value"}"""


lst = json.loads(f"[{', '.join(s.splitlines())}]")
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {"event": "info1xxxxx", "Id": "0001"},
    {"event": "info2xxxxx", "Id": "0002"},
    {"event": "info3xxxxx", "Id": "0003"},
    {"event": "info3xxxxx", "Id": "0003", "other_key": "value"},
]
```